# Blocking URL in .htaccess - why not working?

Tags: .htaccess

My site is attacking by bots and I want to block them.

[01/Jun/2016:11:02:56 +0200] "GET /index.php?option=com_user&view=register HTTP/1.1" 301 804

i was trying

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php?option=com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

but its not working, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the uri from RewriteCond's pattern

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^option=com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: [01/Jun/2016:12:19:33 +0200] "GET /?option=com_k2&view=itemlist&task=user&id=469364 HTTP/1.0" 403 458

bots are getting 403 - thank you !

Comment: but weird thing.

i logs i see `[01/Jun/2016:15:32:23 +0200] "GET /index.php?option=com_user&view=register HTTP/1.1" 301 804`

what is wrong?

Comment: how it is possible?